# custom class to hold perceptron data- possibly not correctly populated

Tags: java, machine-learning, perceptron

I have the following input

```
 0 0 0 0 0  0 2
 0 0 0 0 1  0 2
 0 0 0 1 0  0 2
 0 0 0 1 1  0 2
```

*these are toy values for demonstration*

These are meant to feed a perceptron with two outputs, i.e. the two labels the proceed the tab.

I created a class to hold a set of inputs and a label, so I envision finally two data structures, one for each neuron, in the form of:

```
 0 0 0 0 0  0
 0 0 0 0 1  0
 0 0 0 1 0  0
 0 0 0 1 1  0
```

and

```
 0 0 0 0 0  2
 0 0 0 0 1  2
 0 0 0 1 0  2
 0 0 0 1 1  2
```

The class looks like this:

```
class Group {

   public String key;
   public String[] value;

   public String getKey() {
      return key;
   }

   public String[] getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   Group(String[] splited_inputs, String k) 
   {
      this.key = k;
      this.value = splited_inputs;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return this.key + " " + this.value;
   }
}
```

I populate the class, by reading in the inputs from a file in this way:

```
      ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<>();


    /**************
     * READ INPUT *
     **************/
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("../PA-A-train.dat"));

    String line;//new variable
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) //read the line and compare
    {
        /*********************************************************************
         * GET THE LINE, SPLIT ON THE TAB FOR LABEL VS. INPUT IDENTIFICATION *
         *********************************************************************/
        String[] label_detector = line.split("\t"); //split

        /*****************************
         * GET THE INDIVIDUAL INPUTS *
         *****************************/
        String inputs = label_detector[label_detector.length - 2];
        String[] splited_inputs = inputs.split("\\s+");

        splited_inputs = Arrays.stream(splited_inputs) //Remove null values
                .filter(s -> (s != null && s.length() > 0))
                .toArray(String[]::new); 

        //for this training datum, how many features does it have
        int number_of_inputs = splited_inputs.length;   //5     

        /************************************
         * GET THE LABEL (2nd LAYER OUTPUT) *
         ************************************/
        String trueLabel = label_detector[label_detector.length - 1];
        //System.out.println("this is the corresponding label: " + trueLabel);
        String[] splited_labels = trueLabel.split("\\s+");

        int number_of_labels = splited_labels.length;           


      list.add(new Group(splited_inputs, splited_labels[0]));



    }
    reader.close();

    for (Group p : list)
        System.out.println( "check it out: " + p.toString() );


}
```

**BUT** when I try to print it, the output looks like this:

```
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@87aac27
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@3e3abc88
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@6ce253f1
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@53d8d10a
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@e9e54c2
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@65ab7765
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@1b28cdfa
check it out: 1 [Ljava.lang.String;@eed1f14
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@7229724f
check it out: 0 [Ljava.lang.String;@4c873330
```

So it's printing the location in memeory and not the array of inputes.

Is this because I'm originally inserting the location in memory only or because I'm not iterating over it to print it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly call `toString()` on arrays in java to print the contents.

However, you can use `Arrays.toString(Object[] arr)`

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return this.key + " " + Arrays.toString(this.value);
}
```

Comment: this is elegent-er so I choose it, but both answers work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your toString() method:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.key + " " + this.value;
}
```

`this.value` is an array of strings (`String[]`), so its `toString()` method returns something that looks like `[Ljava.lang.String;@106d69c`. Instead, you could loop over `this.value` and concatenate each of those to your result:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = this.key;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.value.length; i++) {
        result += " " + this.value[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Better yet, you can use `String.join(delimiter, elements)`:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.key + " " + String.join(" ", this.value);
}
```

The output won't have square brackets like `Arrays.toString()` will.

Comment: this is a great answer- thank you- it helped me to understand a lot- but i selected the other because it is a bit more consise.

Comment: See the updated answer for another concise way of printing, but this time without the square brackets (I'm not sure which you prefer, but this is a cool trick to know).